# ZURB Foundation - Using Flex Video inside a Section

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to add a Vimeo video inside a [ZURB Foundation Section](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/section.html) (aka Tabs). The entire `<section>` is responsive, and so should the video inside the tab. To make the video player responsive I'm using Foundation's built-in [Flex Video](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/flex-video.html).

When the section with the video is opened the `<section>` has zero (or near zero) height. I have tried to use the `reflow` method but no luck with that route.

Is there a way to redraw the `<section>`, or it's contents after the section has been opened?

Here's a JSFiddle of the issue - http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/8KKGS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys this is a problem I raised an issue for. I believe the way Foundation is applying a style to not be the best approach.

This is caused by padding-bottom = 0 being applied to the last element in a section. You can override it for now by putting this in your .scss somewhere:

```
.flex-video {
    padding-bottom: 67.5% !important;
}
```

There is a pull request here for a permanent fix: 
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2412

and an issue I raised to address the padding problem here:
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2502

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering I found a hack--ish solution using a placeholder image to maintain the correct size. One caveat is the image must be the same (or nearly the same) proportions as the video. Not perfect, but it works.

I also had to change the HTML of the `<section>` a bit but nothing major.

Here's a [JSFiddle showing the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/h4Bjs/).

Hope it helps someone down the road.